# How do I resolve the git-svn error 'refs/remotes/git-svn$: command returned error: 1'?

Tags: git, svn

In the process of converting a Subversion repository to git, you might encounter the following error while converting `svn:ignore` settings to `.gitignore`:

> `config --get svn-remote.svn.fetch :refs/remotes/git-svn$: command returned error: 1`

How do I resolve this error?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To resolve this error, specify the `GIT_SVN_ID` refname you want to fetch information from. Like:

```
git svn show-ignore -i trunk > .gitignore
```

Comment: Try this `git svn show-ignore -i origin/trunk > .gitignore` if above not works.